# How to get max value using MDX Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssas, mdx, cube

I'm trying to get maximum value for Dimension table where the data as referred with Fact table

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Max key] AS 
    Max
    (
      [DimAnchorDate].[Date Key].MEMBERS
     ,[DimAnchorDate].[Date Key].CurrentMember.Member_Key
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Max key]
  } ON COLUMNS
FROM X;
```

This query is giving me output : 20141231
In FactTable we have data upto 20141031. From the above query I would like to get 20141031

[image]

So now I am trying to get max value from DimAnchordate table as same as it is coming in FactPatientDr Table (i.e 20141031).So please suggest me the best way to achieve this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think at the moment you are looking at Dates that are empty in certain parts of the cube space - try forcing to `nonempty` by using a measure from the `FactPatientDr`

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Max key] AS 
    Max
    (
      nonempty(
        [DimAnchorDate].[Date Key].MEMBERS
        ,[Measures].[SomeMeasureInFactPatientDr]
      )
     ,[DimAnchorDate].[Date Key].CurrentMember.Member_Key
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Max key]
  } ON COLUMNS
FROM X;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use Tail function to get desired result with measure value as well:

```
select non empty([Measures].[Entered Case],
    tail  
   (Order   
      ([Calendar].[Date].[Date].members  
         ,[Measures].[Entered Case]
         ,basc
      )  
   ,1
   ))   on 0 from [SolutionPartner]
```